# .NET 6 EF Core 6.0.0 Queries with Joins and Where Clause causes ArgumentOutOfRangeException, EF Core 5.0.11 works instead

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Starting with .NET6 and using package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer V6.0.0 we are facing a problem with some of the Linq Queries. Using V5.0.11 the query is working. Perhaps this is a bug but maybe I need to rewrite the query:

```
DbSet<SearchCpPersLegacy>().IgnoreQueryFilters()
.Include(p => p.SearchCpPersMailList)
.Include(p => p.SearchCpPersTelList)
.Include(p => p.SearchDsIpidPers)
.Include(p => p.IpidVip)
.Include(p => p.SearchUserAnrede)
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<SearchCpPersAdrLegacy>(), 
    outerKeySelector: pers => pers.PersId, 
    innerKeySelector: adr => adr.PersId, 
    resultSelector: (pers, adr) => new { 
        pers = pers, 
        adr = adr
     })
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<SearchCpPersKvLegacy>(), 
    outerKeySelector: t => t.pers.PersId, 
    innerKeySelector: kv => kv.PersId, 
    resultSelector: (t, kv) => new { 
        t = t, 
        kv = kv
     })
.Join(
    inner: DbSet<AddressLegacy>(), 
    outerKeySelector: t => t.t.pers.PersId, 
    innerKeySelector: ans => ans.PersId, 
    resultSelector: (t, ans) => new { 
        Adr = t.t.adr, 
        Kv = t.kv, 
        Pers = t.t.pers, 
        Ans = ans
     })
.Where(f => True && f.Adr.Aktiv)
```

If removing the Where Clause in the end the query works fine, but with the Where clause it throws an exception:

> Exception: ArgumentOutOfRangeException
> Message: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')"
> StackTrace: "   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression.GetProjection(ProjectionBindingExpression projectionBindingExpression)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.GetProjectionIndex(ProjectionBindingExpression projectionBindingExpression)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)\n   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitBlockExpressions(ExpressionVisitor visitor, BlockExpression block)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitBlock(BlockExpression node)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.BlockExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)\n   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression node)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache, LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders, Int32& collectionId)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression shapedQueryExpression)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)\n   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.b__0()\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToQueryString(IQueryable source)\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryDebugView.get_Query()"

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't assume EF Core is broken. That query is extremely unusual though, mixing both relations and joins and making reference to non-existent `DbSet<>()` methods. It's impossible to say what this query does without the entities and knowing what those functions do. And that `.Where(f => True && f.Adr.Aktiv)` is no different than `.Where(f => f.Adr.Aktiv)`. Was this an attempt to rewrite SQL as LINQ?

Comment: Actually looks like EF Core bug. But yes, if you are doing joins and `Include` together, something wrong in query and it can be rewritten to be more simple.

Comment: Why `True && f.Adr.Aktiv`? Do you get the same error when just using `f.Adr.Aktiv`? (It's the same condition).

Comment: This is done by the PredicateBuilder from LinqKit, but if adding it without predicate builder with f.Adr.Aktiv only it has the same effect

Comment: After some try-and-error I found the reason for this: The field in the database is not a "bit", it is a "smallint". Therefore we used a conversion rule with ZeroOneToBoolConverter "builder.Property(p => p.Aktiv).HasConversion(new ZeroOneToBoolConverter());" . In .NET  EF Core 6.0.0 the queries fail. After changing to "HasConversion<short>()" it works...

Comment: Additionally the Where clause must be .Where(x => x.Adr.Aktiv == true) Not .Where(x => x.Adr.Aktiv).... Is this a EF Core 6.0.0 bug? Yes I would say